# Using regini from a c# app without bothering the user?

Tags: c#, registry

I am developing an application that needs to use regini (because of legacy reasons) to insert something into the registry. I have been trying to do this in such a way the the user of the application is not aware of this. I have written the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();  

pi.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\regini.exe";
pi.Arguments = name;
pi.WorkingDirectory = Utils.AppSettings.WorkingDirectory.ToString();    
pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pi.RedirectStandardError = true;
pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pi.UseShellExecute = false;  
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = pi;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Start();
```

Unfortunately, I still see the 'command' window pop-up every time this code is executed. I was under the impression that

```
pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

would prevent that. How can I prevent regini from opening its own command window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this line:

```
pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug report on the Microsoft Connect Feedback Site: [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden shows window while executing](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=95026)

Maybe there is a hint of something you forgot.

Comment: Thanks, but the discussion in the link just focusses on the problem of reproducing the issue. Apparently they cannot.